# owl carousel caption animation

Tags: jquery, animation, owl-carousel

i am  using owl carousel  and i want to  start  a **caption animation** when  the slide shows up  i have found  some solutions here and there but it's not working properly , it starts working fine after the second loop  but in the first loop (when refreshing the page and the document is ready)  the first caption animation does not start , this is the code :

```
 <div class="carousel-caption ">
      <p class="display-3 ">Ready To Wear </p>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-light">Shop Now</button>
  </div>


 <style>
.slide-animation{
        animation: HomeslideIn 0.5s forwards ;
        animation-delay: 0.8s;
    }

    @keyframes HomeslideIn{
        from{

        }
        to{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        opacity:1;
        }

    }    
    </style> 


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        var Caroussel = $('.owl-carousel');
        
        
        Caroussel.owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop:true,
            nav:true,
            dots:true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
     
        });
        
        Caroussel.on("changed.owl.carousel", function(event){
                
                // selecting the current active item
                var item = event.item.index-2;
                // first removing animation for all captions
                $('.carousel-caption').removeClass('slide-animation');
                $('.owl-item').not('.cloned').eq(item).find('.carousel-caption').addClass('slide-animation');
            })

        
    })
    

</script>
```